# how to access returned value by twig - silex

Tags: php, twig, silex

I'm new in silex and twig.
I want to access a returned value from a function and put it in my twig template. This is my code :

```
namespace classes;

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
$blogPosts = array(
1 => array(
    'date'      => '2011-03-29',
    'author'    => 'igorw',
    'title'     => 'Using Silex',
    'body'      => '...',
),
);
class GlobalController
{
public function indexAction(Application $app, Request $request)
{

    $output = '';
    foreach ($blogPosts as $post) {
        $output .= $post['title'];
        $output .= '<br />';
    }

  return $output;
      }
    }
```

I want to access $output and show it in my template. Can I do that? because I have other similar functions and they are retrieving data from database and returning them as values, I want to include these values in the template ..
Is that possible ?

I tried these but they didn't work :

```
{{ GlobalController.output }}
{# Or #}
{{ GlobalController.indexAction.output }}
```

**Update :**
I added this in my routing:

```
$app->get('/news/', function () use ($app) {
return $app['twig']->render('news.php.twig', array(
'output' => $output,
));
});
```

and it gave me Undefined variable: output notice.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you're finishing up with your route, you need to show which twig template you're using and include all the variables that you want to use in twig:

```
return $app['twig']->render('some_template.twig', array(
    'output' => $output,
));
```

Now you can access the variable with `{{ output }}`

Comment: Hi .. thanks for commenting , I updated my question.. I added the variables and  it gave me Undefined variable: output notice.

Comment: Well. You have not defined `$output` in the updated code. There's nothing that even mentions it.

Comment: I defined it in the routing : 
`$app->get('/news/', function () use ($app) { return $app['twig']->render('news.php.twig', array( 'output' => $output, )); });`
Am I messing something ?

Comment: I'll just have to repeat myself. There's no `$output` defined in the code that you have provided in the edit.

Comment: Your updated code. Where do you define `$output` since you are using it? The function you're in does not have that variable, that's what PHP is tellingyou.